# Expecting JSON from firebase but getting a list

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using python-firebase library for accessing firebase realtime database. The structure of the database is depicted in [this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGbXi.png)
When I am accessing the node "PatientMaster" using python, I am getting a list of JSONs without the ID's instead of getting a proper JSON key-value format. Could someone please help me with this? The code which I have written for doing the above is:

```
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://************.firebaseio.com', None)
result = firebase.get("/PatientMaster",None)
```

The variable "result" gives me the output as a list of JSONs without ID's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using sequential numeric keys for the records in node 'PatientMaster' and the record contents are very similar. Firebase RTDB interprets (sometimes) that structure as a list array rather than a map array. The reason being that when you post a list array to FB RTDB it stores it as a map (json) with keys 0-n and the list items as the values. When you read the db and it sees this structure it thinks it is a stored list array and returns that instead of a map (json). See this post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html?m=1

You need to make your keys more complex, or test / expect the data returned from this node to be a list array.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! @GrahamD

Comment: Glad I could help - I ran into that a year or so ago and it had me going around in circles for a while. :-) Thanks for the upvote.